# iPhone tabbar application

Tags: iphone

i am making a tabbar based app for iphone.But i cannot add button action to the file's owner.I have seen some tabbar application tutorial.But those only shows how to create an template and add some level.
When i try to connect button action with file's owner it show's no method that i wrote. Please help me about addding button action.

Comment: 1. Did you save the changes before going to Interface Builder?
2. Provide the code of the

Comment: source code is big....my code works in a view based app..so i think code is ok...